# Do I mention the involved mathematics in my patent application?

Tags: description

My application is for a hardware based patent, however, there's a significant mathematical relation, which completes my invention. I haven't seen mathematical equations being described in applications, so should I mention the equation?

Comment: This question needs more information as to how the math relates to the invention.

Comment: Is the mathematics required to enable the invention? If so, I think you need to show the equations. I have patents which have equations in them.